Solve a double integral where one of the limits contains a variable
I'm trying to solve for a volume using a double integral.  My issue is that I am not sure what to do about one of the limits of an integral containing a variable.
Here is the general equation for the volume:
$$V = \int^{2\pi}_0\int^{r_i}_0hrdrd\phi$$
$h$ and $r$ are separate variables. The equation for the product $hr$ is:
$$hr = \frac{R^2\sin^3\beta}{(1-\cos\beta\cos\phi)^2}$$
The equation for $r_i$ is
$$r_i = \frac{R\sin\beta}{1- \cos\beta\cos\phi}$$
Any time that the integral is evaluated, $\sin \beta, \cos \beta$ and $R$ are constant. Solving the integral associated with $dr$ where everything but $r$ is constant yields,
$$V = \int^{2\pi}_0\frac{R^2\sin^3\beta}{(1-\cos\beta\cos\phi)^2}\left[\frac{R\sin\beta}{(1- \cos\beta\cos\phi)}-0 \right]d\phi$$
This reduces to,
$$V = R^3\sin^4\beta\int^{2\pi}_0\frac{1}{(1-\cos\beta\cos\phi)^3}d\phi$$
I would appreciate it if someone could validate that the way I handled the limit, $r_i$, is correct.  Also, if the last equation is correct, if someone could point me to the solution for the integral that would be great.  Preferably a simplified solution, if it exists, as opposed to the complicated one provided by Wolfram-Alpha.  By that I mean that if the following is integrated (where the exponent is 2 and not 3),
$$\int^{2\pi}_0\frac{1}{(1-\cos\beta\cos\phi)^2}d\phi$$
the solution is
$$\frac{2 \pi}{(1-\cos^2\beta)^{3/2}} = \frac{2 \pi}{\sin^3 \beta}$$
whereas W-A provides a very complicated solution.

No.  The equation is correct as written. The product of h and r is the equation shown.

This is contradictory: $\frac1r\frac{R^2\sin^3\beta}{(1-\cos\beta\cos\phi)^2}$ is not a function of $\phi$ alone, but of $(\phi,r)$.

FWIW, the integral in $V$ evaluates to$$\pi\frac{2+\cos^2\beta}{\sin^5\beta}$$found via contour integration. Are you interested in that approach, or are you looking for a more elementary method?

@Anne Bauval:  Ah, I think I see what you mean. In the equations h only shows as being a function of $\phi$, which it clearly is not.  I'll edit the post, but none of the equations will effectively be changed.  I'll just replace $h(\phi)$ with $h$.  Thanks for the correction.

@user170231: I have inserted your result into the eqn. for V and compared it to what W-A calculates when I supply W-A with the values for $\sin \beta, \cos \beta$ and R.  I tested for 6 values of $\beta$ and one value of R (namely R = 1). The W-A results agree with what is calculated using the result you provided.  I am interested in a  more elementary approach as I know nothing about contour integration.

The tangent half-angle substitution is a good choice here, which we prepare for by first translating $\phi\to\phi+\pi$. Later, the partial fraction expansion is easy to come by, and the subsequent integrals are susceptible to standard trigonometric substitutions. We also make frequent use of the identity
$$\tan^2\frac\beta2 = \frac{\sin^2\frac\beta2}{\cos^2\frac\beta2} = \frac{1-\cos\beta}{1+\cos\beta}$$

$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\phi}{(1-\cos\beta \cos\phi)^3} \\
&= \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{d\phi}{(1+\cos\beta \cos\phi)^3} \\
&= 2 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\left(1+u^2\right)^2}{\left(1+\cos\beta + (1-\cos\beta) u^2\right)^3} \, du & \phi=2\arctan u \\
&= \frac2{(1-\cos\beta)^3} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\left(1+u^2\right)^2}{\left(\cot^2\frac\beta2 + u^2\right)^3} \, du \\
&= \frac{2\tan^5\frac\beta2}{(1-\cos\beta)^3} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\left(1+\cot^2\frac\beta2 \, v^2\right)^2}{\left(1 + v^2\right)^3} \, dv & u = \cot\frac\beta2\,v \\
&= \frac{2t}{(1-\cos\beta)^3} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac1{1+v^2} + \frac{2(t-1) }{\left(1+v^2\right)^2} + \frac{(t-1)^2}{\left(1+v^2\right)^3}\right) \, dv & \left[t=\tan\frac\beta2\right] \\ \\
&= \frac{2t}{(1-\cos\beta)^3} \int_{-\tfrac\pi2}^\tfrac\pi2 \left(1 + 2\left(t^2-1\right)\cos^2w + \left(t^2-1\right)^2 \cos^4w\right) \, dw & v=\tan w \\
&= \frac{2t}{(1-\cos\beta)^3} \left(\pi + 2\left(t^2-1\right)\cdot\frac\pi2 + \left(t^2-1\right)^2\cdot\frac{3\pi}8\right) \\
&= \frac{\pi}{4(1-\cos\beta)^3} \left(3t + 2t^3 + 3t^5\right) \\
&= \pi \frac{2+\cos^2\beta}{\sin^5\beta}
\end{align*}$$
